# OpenAI gym's breakout-v0 "pauses"

Tags: openai-gym

While training in the OpenAI gym environment I have the idea that the environment sometimes "stops". For many frames in a row no ball is visible/stops spawning.

Is this an error in the gym environment? Is this something that is part of the game Breakout-v0?

I was also wondering what the possible actions are in Breakout-v0. What I kind of figured out:

0 - do nothing/stand still?

1 - do nothing/stand still?

2 - apply "force" to the right?

3 - apply "force" to the left?

Edit: 
For people wondering what I'm talking about: see this gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F4oR.jpg
The transition between 5 and 4 lives takes a lot of frames... Sometimes the break is even longer than this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its cause after end of life your agent needs to hit the fire button to get the game to start playing again. If it doesn't learn to do this then the game will not progress and looked paused like you say it seems.

I believe actions off the top of my head are:

0: no-op
1: fire
2: right
3: left

could be other way around on directions

Comment: Thanks! I can believe that this is true. Unfortunately my agent does not seem to learn it. Thanks for the answer!