# DQN Atari with tensorflow: Training seems to stuck

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to learn a DQ-Learning Network to play Breakout Atari in Tensorflow. The code runs without problems, but always after 1000-1200 episodes, the time for executing one step explodes to over 100s.
Here is my **DQN**:

```
class DQNetwork():
    def __init__(self, scope, state_size=(84, 84, 4), num_outputs=4, gamma=0.9, learning_rate=0.001):
        
        self.scope = scope
        

        with tf.variable_scope(self.scope):

            # ---------------------
            # Basic Deep Q-Network
            # ---------------------
            self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, *state_size], name="inputs")
            
            # Input is 84x84x4
            self.conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs = self.x,
                                         filters = 32,
                                         kernel_size = [8,8],
                                         strides = [4,4],
                                         padding = "VALID",
                                         name = "conv1",
                                         activation="relu")
            
            self.conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs = self.conv1,
                                 filters = 64,
                                 kernel_size = [4,4],
                                 strides = [2,2],
                                 padding = "VALID",
                                 name = "conv2",
                                activation="relu")

            self.conv3 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs = self.conv2,
                                 filters = 64,
                                 kernel_size = [3,3],
                                 strides = [1,1],
                                 padding = "VALID",
                                 name = "conv3",
                                activation="relu")
            
            self.flatten = tf.layers.flatten(self.conv3)
            
            self.fc = tf.layers.dense(inputs = self.flatten,
                                  units = 512,
                                  activation = tf.nn.relu,
                                name="fc1")
            
            self.logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs = self.fc,
                                          units = num_outputs, 
                                        activation=None)
            

            self.best_action = tf.argmax(self.logits, name="best_action", axis=1)
            self.max_q = tf.reduce_max(self.logits, name="max_q", axis=1)
               
            if scope == 'Target':
                self.rewards = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=None, name="rewards")    
                self.gamma = tf.constant(gamma, name="Gamma")
                self.done = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=None, name="done_values")

               
                self.td_target = self.rewards + (self.gamma*self.max_q) * tf.cast( tf.abs(self.done -1 ), tf.float32)
              
                
            if scope == 'Q':
                self.target_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=None, name="target_placeholder_q")  
                
                self.actions = tf.placeholder(tf.uint8, shape=None, name="AllActions")
                self.actions_onehot = tf.one_hot(self.actions, depth=num_outputs, name="One_Hot")  
                self.Q = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(self.actions_onehot, self.logits))
                
                self.huber_loss = huber_loss(self.target_placeholder-self.Q)
                self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(self.huber_loss)
                
                self.optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate, epsilon=0.01)
                self.train = self.optimizer.minimize(self.loss, name="minimize")
```

**Huber Loss Function**:

```
def huber_loss(x, delta=1.0):
    """Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss"""
    return tf.where(
        tf.abs(x) < delta,
        tf.square(x) * 0.5,
        delta * (tf.abs(x) - 0.5 * delta)
    )
```

**Preprocess Frames**

```
def preprocess_frame(obs):
    processed_observe = np.uint8(
        resize(rgb2gray(obs), (84, 84), mode='constant') * 255)
    return processed_observe
```

**ReplayBuffer**

```
class ReplayBuffer():
    def __init__(self, buffer_size):
        self.buffer = deque([], maxlen=buffer_size)

    def add(self, new_state):
        if len(new_state) != 5:
            raise Exception("States must have: state, action, reward, next_state, done")
        self.buffer.append(new_state)

    def sample(self, batch_size):
        return r.sample(self.buffer, batch_size)
```

**Update Target Network**

```
def get_update_target_ops(Q_network, Target_network):

    # You code comes here     
    # 1. get the trainable variables per network
    Q_trainable = tf.trainable_variables(scope=Q_network.scope)
    Target_trainable = tf.trainable_variables(scope=Target_network.scope)
    
    # 2. sort them with sorted(list, key=attrgetter())
    Q_trainable  = sorted(Q_trainable, key=attrgetter("name"))
    Target_trainable  = sorted(Target_trainable, key=attrgetter("name"))

    
    # 3.create a new list with all assign ops
    update_target_expr = []
    for q_var, t_var in zip(Q_trainable, Target_trainable):
        update_target_expr.append(t_var.assign(q_var))

    return update_target_expr
```

**Greedy Action**

```
def choose_egreedy_action(session, epsilon, network, state):
    state = np.float32(state / 255.0)
    
    if np.random.rand() <= epsilon:
        return np.random.randint(0, n)
    else:
        state_reshaped = np.reshape(state, (1, *obs_space))
        best_action = session.run(network.best_action, feed_dict={network.x:state_reshaped})[0]
        return best_action
```

**Linear Schedule**

```
class LinearSchedule():
 
    def __init__(self, start_epsilon, final_epsilon, pre_train_steps, decay):
        
        self.start_epsilon = start_epsilon
        self.final_epsilon = final_epsilon
        self.pre_train_steps = pre_train_steps
        
        
        self.decay = decay
        self.epsilon = start_epsilon

    def value(self, t):
        if t <= self.pre_train_steps:
            return self.start_epsilon
        else:
            return self.start_epsilon - (t-self.pre_train_steps)*self.decay
```

**Train Step**

```
def train(sess, Q, Target, buffer, batch_size):

    # You code comes here     
    # 1. Sample from the replay buffer
    mini_batches = buffer.sample(batch_size)
    
    
    
    observations, actions, rewards, next_observations, done,  = map(list, zip(*mini_batches))
    
    observations = np.array(observations)/255.
    next_observations =np.array(next_observations)/255.
    td_targets = sess.run( Target.td_target, feed_dict={Target.x : next_observations, Target.rewards:rewards, Target.done:done})

    max_q, loss, _ = sess.run([Q.max_q, Q.loss, Q.train], feed_dict={Q.x : observations, Q.target_placeholder:td_targets, Q.actions:actions})
    
    return loss
```

**Hyperparams**

```
EPISODES = 50000
epsilon = 1.
epsilon_start, epsilon_end = 1.0, 0.1
exploration_steps = 1000000.
epsilon_decay_step = (epsilon_start - epsilon_end) / exploration_steps

batch_size = 32
train_start = 50000
update_target_rate = 10000
gamma = 0.99
buffer_size = 400000
no_op_steps = 30

global_steps = 10000000
```

**Init networks**

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

Q_network  = DQNetwork(scope="Q", state_size=(84, 84, 4), num_outputs=4, gamma=gamma, learning_rate=0.00025)
T_network = DQNetwork(scope="Target",state_size=(84, 84, 4), num_outputs=4, gamma=gamma, learning_rate=0.00025)
update_target_network = get_update_target_ops(Q_network,T_network)
```

**Train Loop**

```
from tqdm import trange
import random
game = gym.make('BreakoutDeterministic-v4')
scores, episodes = [], [], 

with tf.Session() as sess:
    
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        buffer = ReplayBuffer(buffer_size)


        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        epsilon_schedule = LinearSchedule(epsilon_start, epsilon_end, train_start, epsilon_decay_step)
        
        done = False
        dead = False
        # 1 episode = 5 lives
        step, score, start_life = 0, 0, 5
        observe = game.reset()
        eps = 0
        # this is one of DeepMind's idea.
        # just do nothing at the start of episode to avoid sub-optimal
        for _ in range(random.randint(1, no_op_steps)):
            observe, _, _, _ = game.step(1)
            
        # At start of episode, there is no preceding frame
        # So just copy initial states to make history
        state = preprocess_frame(observe)
        history = np.stack((state, state, state, state), axis=2)
        history = np.reshape([history], (84, 84, 4))    
        
        loss = 0
        
        for global_step in trange(global_steps):
            #global_step += 1
            step += 1

            # get action for the current history and go one step in environment
            action = choose_egreedy_action(sess, epsilon, Q_network, history)

            observe, reward, done, info = game.step(action)


            # pre-process the observation --> history
            next_state = preprocess_frame(observe)
            next_state = np.reshape([next_state], (84, 84, 1))
            #print(next_state.shape)
            next_history = np.append(next_state, history[ :, :, :3], axis=2)


            # if the agent missed ball, agent is dead --> episode is not over
            if start_life > info['ale.lives']:
                dead = True
                start_life = info['ale.lives']

            #if dead:
                #reward = -1
                
            #score += reward
            
            reward = np.clip(reward, -1., 1.)

            # save the sample <s, a, r, s'> to the replay memory
            buffer.add([history, action, reward, next_history, dead])


            epsilon = epsilon_schedule.value(global_step)


            if global_step > train_start:
                train(sess, Q_network, T_network, buffer, batch_size)

            # update the target model with model
            if global_step % update_target_rate == 0:
                #print("update networks")
                sess.run(update_target_network) 

            score += reward

            # if agent is dead, then reset the history
            if dead:
                dead = False
            else:
                history = next_history

            # if done, plot the score over episodes
            if done:
                if eps%100 == 0:  
                    print("episode:", eps, "  score:", score, " global_step: ", global_step,
                         " epsilon: ", epsilon)
                scores.append(score)
                episodes.append(step)
                
                done = False
                dead = False
                # 1 episode = 5 lives
                step, score, start_life = 0, 0, 5
                observe = game.reset()
                eps +=  1
                # this is one of DeepMind's idea.
                # just do nothing at the start of episode to avoid sub-optimal
                for _ in range(random.randint(1, no_op_steps)):
                    observe, _, _, _ = game.step(1)

                # At start of episode, there is no preceding frame
                # So just copy initial states to make history
                state = preprocess_frame(observe)
                history = np.stack((state, state, state, state), axis=2)
                history = np.reshape([history], (84, 84, 4))   
                
                
                

            if global_step % 5000 == 0:
                saver.save(sess, f'models/breakout/model_breakout.ckpt')
```

For the first 50.000 steps (no training) I have s.th. like `400it/s`, which seems to be fine. After that it is s.th. about `50it/s`. As soon as `epsilon` descreases, this number also descreases because we more often have to use the best action instead of a random one.

But after about 1000 episodes i get s.th. like:

```
 2%|▏         | 174582/10000000 [46:53<43:59:11, 100s/it]  epsilon:0.88, score: 2
```

As you can see the duration per iteration increases very much, therefore the training seems to stuck.
I don't know whether this is a problem with my GPU or with the code.

Do you have any idea what to do?

Comment: sry my fault. Changed it;)

Comment: Any idea is helpful!:)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience whilst using an RL algorithm and training on the Atari Breakout environment from openAI gym. It happened after my exploration rate dropped to a very low value. I found the solution from this post: [OpenAI gym's breakout-v0 "pauses"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44777068/openai-gyms-breakout-v0-pauses)

I knew my problem was similar to that post because when I rendered the game frames for each episode, I saw that after a life was lost in Atari Breakout, the ball disappeared (it was paused).

The reason why it didn't pause at the beginning of my training, was because the exploration rate was high and it was taking random actions when paused which would have lead it to choosing an action that would start the game.

=================

I think this may solve your problem, not sure if it will (and it is usually not recommended in RL)

See this post:
[OpenAI gym breakout-ram-v4 unable to learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57149560/openai-gym-breakout-ram-v4-unable-to-learn?rq=1)

So the question in the above post mentions that the algorithm sets the reward to -1 when the agent loses a life. It does the this by making use of the system information (given when .step() is called) to detect when a life is lost. I'm thinking when you detect a life is lost in Atari Breakout, you hard code that the agent must choose the action (for the next step) that starts the game.

Again, this approach is not recommended in RL cause the agent only supposed to make use of the observation when deciding on which action to take.